# Cordova PhoneGap capture video in mp4 type with minimum size

Tags: cordova, video, phonegap

I am using the code below to capture the video. How do I capture the mp4 video with the minimum size possible?

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {
    duration: 60, limit: 1, type: "video/3gpp",
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    quality: 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the options you currently have quality set to 0, this means the video will be low quality and suitable for MMS messages. If you want to further reduce the size, you could reduce the height and/or width of the video.

Comment: Yes correct but its not working,In few device it make 3gp(with low size kb in 60 sec)
 and in some mp4(but with big size 50mb 60 sec),

Comment: What android versions are you testing? Which ones produce the low file size?

Comment: fine on 7.0 Android Redmi Note 4 my device it create 3gp ,but on client device (Samsung device) it make 50 mb mp4